# Multiple Pages Inside One Portlet

Tags: java, jsp, portlet

I am curious if anyone knows if it is possible for a single portlet to contain multiple pages, let's say JSP pages. Furthermore is it possible to link to these different pages within the same portlet?

For example. Let's say I have a single portlet. And in this portlet I want the initial view to be a JSP page with just 5 links on it to 5 different JSP pages. And when a user clicked on one of these 5 links, it would load the appropriate JSP page into the portlet.

The end goal would basically be a little mini website all contained inside a portlet.

Now, I understand that this might not be the best use of a portlet, but for the sake of a project I am working on, I still would like to know if it is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, a portlet can contain more than one JSP.

You can display any JSP you want via the [PortletRequestDispatcher](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-1.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletRequestDispatcher.html) in your [doView](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-1.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/GenericPortlet.html#doView(javax.portlet.RenderRequest,%20javax.portlet.RenderResponse)) (or `doHelp` or `doEdit`) method:

```
protected void doView(RenderRequest req, RenderResponse resp)
       throws PortletException, IOException, UnavailableException {
   resp.setContentType("text/html"); 
   String myview = req.getParameter("myview");
   String view = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" + (myview==null ? "bar" : myview) + ".jsp";
   PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
                                 getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(view);
   dispatcher.include(req, resp);
}
```

You could use a [parameter](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-1.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) to set the view. In the JSP with the links, you'd need to use the Portlet API to create/encode the links to the Portlet. For example:

```
<portlet:renderURL>
  <portlet:param name="myview" value="foo"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

*(I haven't really kept abreast of JSR286/Portlet 2.0 - this stuff should work with JSR168/Portlet 1.0 - so it is worth checking the new API if you're using it.)*